# Sharepoint Project Server - PWA Timesheet Rest Api

Tags: rest, sharepoint, project-server

I want to send the Timesheet weekly period in Sharepoint PWA to my Timesheet manager for approval with the Turn in Final Timesheet operation. I want to make an application that will perform this operation with Rest Api. I need a sample javascript code.

I could only find this from Microsft sources but I could not get it to work

POST http:////_api/ProjectServer/TimeSheetPeriods('periodid')/TimeSheet/submit(comment)

Source
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/project-javascript-api/jj668473(v=office.15)